# Android and python communication

Tags: android, python, mysql, communication

I did build an app that asks you a few questions and you pick the answer via button presses and send you to the next question in android studio, this is working perfectly.

My question is how can I go about sending this data (answered questions) to a python code im running on a PC. I want the app to send the data somehow somewhere so that my python code can get it and then put it into readable data like excel, I want to see how many times a specific answer was selected for a specific question?

I'm just looking for a simple solution for my app to store the data somewhere and the my python code retrieving it and working its magic, both sides are working perfectly I just dont have a solution for the middle. I tried setting up an SQL database but I'm not getting it right.

What could be the best solution for that ?

Comment: Write a rest api using [django](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and consume it in your android app.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that come to my mind is to use Google Sheets. You can access it from your Android application using their API:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

And retrieve it with python, they also provide a python API for that:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: There is a lot of solutions to your problem, that's one answer that doesn't ask you to set up your own server. You're welcome

Comment: i am busy setting it up now, will keep you posted thanks

Comment: this is working in some sense but not exactly what im looking for. can you please help me setting up an sql database what do i need and how do i go about doing it? sql just have more features id like to use than google sheets?

Comment: I won't help you setting up an *SQL* database here because this is not what the question is about. Furthermore it's not a trivial thing to do, depending on how familiar you are with setting up *SQL* servers, which I assume you aren't otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question. If I was you I would go like this: Learn how to setup your own database server, then learn how to access it from Android and then from Python.

Comment: okay, im still trying the sheets api thing but there is not alot of help out there so im figuring it out as im going...